# Failed at the myproject@1.0.0 build script 'webpack'

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-universal

I am using [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) as backbone.

When I run `npm start`, I got the error:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/hongbo-miao/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/node" "/Users/hongbo-miao/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! myproject@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@1.0.0 build script 'webpack'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myproject package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     webpack
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs myproject
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls myproject
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/hongbo-miao/projects/myproject/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/hongbo-miao/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/node" "/Users/hongbo-miao/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! myproject@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@1.0.0 prestart script 'npm run build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myproject package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs myproject
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls myproject
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/hongbo-miao/projects/myproject/npm-debug.log
```

I tried the walkaround way mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/176), which let webpack back to version 2.1.0-beta.22

```
npm uninstall webpack --save-dev
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev
```

However, I still got this issue.

Is there anything else that may cause this issue? Thanks

Comment: might be your webpack is upgraded too 23.beta please check the webpack version

Comment: @CodeBuster I tried `npm uninstall webpack --save-dev`, `npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev`. And even global one `npm install -g webpack@2.1.0-beta.22`, but still same issue...

Comment: i faced similar issue , that was because webpack version , i guess this error is because of version issue (might be some packages or npm ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most people, the problem may be because you updated to latest `webpack@2.1.0-beta.23`(has breaking change) while you haven't updated **webpack.config.ts** yet.

So you can do

```
npm uninstall webpack --save-dev
npm install webpack@2.1.0-beta.22 --save-dev
```

However, my mistake is that I change from

```
styles: [
  require('./app.component.scss')
],
```

to

```
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
```

But I didn't set up webpack correctly, so when I change back, it works again now.

So I guess this error will happen whenever there is a mistake in **webpack.config.ts**. It just does not say clear where is the mistake.